# how to clone stash repo on my machine?

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I have got Jenkins(open source) on my machine with artifactory, sonar, git plugins. I have my repo on stash and I want to clone it on my machine.

I have added my own ssh key in my stash account. I am trying this command in my terminal:

```
ssh clone my_clone_url_provided_in_stash
```

But I get this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname clone: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I think I am missing some steps in the process. What should I do?

Honestly I am don't know why do I need Jenkins for cloning... My cloning repo should be independent of my Jenkins account.

Comment: _Honestly I am don't know why do I need Jenkins for cloning... My cloning repo should be independent of my Jenkins account_ - You most definitely do not need Jenkins to clone a git repository - you just need to do `git clone <url>`. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

The correct terminal command is `git clone`, not `ssh clone`. Try this:

```
git clone my_clone_url_provided_in_stash
```